# CakePHP 1.3 - json REST call not displaying correctly

Tags: xml, json, cakephp, rest, cakephp-1.3

I followed [this tutorial](http://www.tutkiun.com/2011/01/data-exchange-in-cakephp-xml-json.html) to set up my REST webservice for JSON and XML. XML outputs properly but when I make a JSON call I get the view not found display from Cake.

To do this I added the following code in my AppController:

```
     if ( $this->RequestHandler->isAjax() ) {
        //Configure::write ( 'debug', 0 );
        $this->layout = 'ajax';
        $this->autoRender = false;      
      } elseif  ($this->RequestHandler->isXml()) {
        $this->layout = 'default';      
        //Configure::write ( 'debug', 0 );
      } elseif ($this->RequestHandler->ext == 'json') { 
        $this->RequestHandler->setContent('json','text/x-json');  
        $this->layout = 'default';      
      } elseif ($this->RequestHandler->accepts('html')) {
        $this->layout = 'frontend';     
      }
```

And this is an example of the code in one of my controller methods:

```
      if ($this->RequestHandler->isXml()) {
        $voicenote = $voicenote['Voicenote'];
        $this->set(compact('voicenote'));
      } else if ($this->RequestHandler->ext == 'json') {
        $voicenote = $voicenote['Voicenote'];
        pr($voicenote);
        echo json_encode(array('voicenote' => $voicenote));                                                                                                                                             
      } else {
        $this->set(compact('voicenote', 'tiny_list'));                                                                                                                                                  
      }
```

XML displays properly, it's just JSON that's the issue.

Comment: Are you testing the json with an AJAX request, or just entering the URL in a browser?

Comment: Just the URL, I get the view not found CakePHP default view, but I know it's going through the right channels because I print out the result of the call and I can see the JSON array

Comment: How is the JSON not displaying properly? `application/json` is the standard content-type for JSON rather than `text/x-json`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that auto-render is only being disabled if the request is performed via an AJAX request.
When entering the address in a browser address bar, after the `echo json_encode();` call, the controller will continue on in the render pipeline, looking for an action and layout template to output.

---

I would suggest being consistent between your XML and JSON rendering, and output both through template files and not disable autoRender for AJAX requests.

AppController:

```
if  ($this->RequestHandler->isXml()) { // Allow a json request to specify XML formatting
  $this->RequestHandler->respondAs('xml'); // for setting headers
  $this->RequestHandler->renderAs($this, 'xml'); // for specifying templates for rendering
} elseif ($this->RequestHandler->ext == 'json'|| $this->RequestHandler->isAjax()){ // 'action' ajax requests and all 'action.json' requests receive JSON
  $this->RequestHandler->respondAs('json');
  $this->RequestHandler->renderAs($this, 'json');
}
// Other requests will fall through to the default HTML rendering
```

Your controller only needs to set the data, and each view template will format it as necessary:

```
function action() {
  // ...
  $voicenote = $voicenote['Voicenote'];
  $this->set(compact('voicenote', 'tiny_list'));                                                                                
}
```

The JSON templates will be relatively simple, create as required by the error messages.
Layout:

```
<?php echo $content_for_layout; ?>
```

JSON Action (app/views/*controller*/json/*action*.ctp)

```
<?php echo json_encode(array('voicenote' => $voicenote)); ?>
```

---

Check out the [CakePHP RequestHandler documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/1291/Request-Handling) for more help

Comment: Got this on the RenderAs line Fatal error: Cannot pass parameter 1 by reference in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/fonykweb/app/app_controller.php on line 35

Comment: I missed that renderAs() requires passing the controller as the first parameter, so the correct call is renderAs($this, 'json').  I updated the code in my answer as well.